# Override parent's border bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create simple tabs and my goal is to emphasize the current tab with a red border. By default, my parent div has grey border. What I'm trying to reach is selected button's red border should override the grey one:

```css
.tab {
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.tabs {
  width: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab">New</button>
  <button class="tab">Archive</button>
</div>
```

is there a way I can achieve it without changing the structure?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov this will not override parent's border but rather add a new one right upon it

Comment: Are you using any JS or jQuery?

Comment: @Desiigner what do you mean by override exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give a class `selected` with right property and toggle with js

a POC:

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("tab")) {
    for (const tab of tabs) {
      tab.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    e.target.classList.add("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
.tab {
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.tab.selected {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.tabs {
  width: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab selected">New</button>
  <button class="tab">Archive</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Edge and IE support then use `focus:within`:

```css
.tab {
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.tabs {
  width: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.tabs:focus-within {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab">New</button>
  <button class="tab">Archive</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have changed code a little bit for tabs to show active and inactive state. Please look for the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tab.active').parent().addClass('tab-active');
  $('.tab').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}
.tab.active,.tabs.tab-active {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
.tabs {
  width: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab active">New</button>
  <button class="tab">Archive</button>
</div>
```